# Xamarin open hyperlink in native webview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing a chat app in xamarin.forms. For my chat label, I used a custom label that could automatically detect HTTP Web Links. The link I followed is [HyperLink Label](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/so-i-created-this-awesomehyperlinklabel-custom-renderer-control-one-day-for-xamarin-forms/comment-page-1/?unapproved=1572&moderation-hash=8424708fba50dda0fbab28813347bfa6#comment-1572). It works well, the URLs are highlighted and open in the default browser but I'd like to be able to catch the URL click event and open an internal browser or webview instead. Currently, the hyperlink click will open suggestions for choosing the other browser applications. I see this similar question in [xamarin.forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70903/i-would-like-to-open-hyperlinks-in-app-using-webview-rather-than-an-external-browser). But I didn't understand the solution. So how can I open the hyperlink in the internal browser or webview? Any help is appreciated.

Hyperlink detector label

```
public class AwesomeHyperLinkLabel : Label
    {

    }
```

**Android Part**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabel), typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer))]
namespace WhateverYourNamespace
{
    public class AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (AwesomeHyperLinkLabel)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
            textView.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            textView.SetTextColor(view.TextColor.ToAndroid());

        // Setting the auto link mask to capture all types of link-able data
            textView.AutoLinkMask = MatchOptions.All;
        // Make sure to set text after setting the mask
            textView.Text = view.Text;
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)view.FontSize);

        // overriding Xamarin Forms Label and replace with our native control
            SetNativeControl(textView);
        }
    }
}
```

**IOS Part**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabel), typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer))]
namespace WhateverYourNamespace
{
    public class AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (AwesomeHyperLinkLabel)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            UITextView uilabelleftside = new UITextView(new CGRect(0, 0, view.Width, view.Height));
            uilabelleftside.Text = view.Text;
            uilabelleftside.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize((float)view.FontSize);
            uilabelleftside.Editable = false;

        // Setting the data detector types mask to capture all types of link-able data
            uilabelleftside.DataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorType.All;
            uilabelleftside.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

        // overriding Xamarin Forms Label and replace with our native control
            SetNativeControl(uilabelleftside);
        }
    }
}
```

**My XAML**

```
<controls:HyperLinkLabel TextColor="White"  Text="www.google.com" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the web in WebView . You could open a new Content Page when click the label .

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new WebContentPage(source));
```

#### WebContentPage

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
     <WebView Source="{Binding source}" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

```
public HtmlWebViewSource source { get; set; }

public WebContentPage(string Websource)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { BaseUrl=Websource};

  BindingContext = this;
}
```

#### Update

```
        var urlStr = "12122wwwww.google.com";

        int startIndex=0, endIndex=0;

        if(urlStr.Contains("www."))
        {
            startIndex = urlStr.IndexOf("www.");
        }

        if (urlStr.Contains(".com"))
        {
            endIndex = urlStr.IndexOf(".com")+3;
        }

        if(startIndex != 0&& endIndex!=0)
        {
            var formattedString = new FormattedString();

            Span span1 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(0,startIndex) , TextColor = Color.Black,FontSize=20};
           
            formattedString.Spans.Add(span1);

            Span span2 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(startIndex, endIndex-startIndex+1), TextColor = Color.Blue, FontSize = 20};
            span2.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer() { NumberOfTapsRequired = 1, Command = new Command(() => { }) } );

            formattedString.Spans.Add(span2);

            Span span3 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(endIndex, urlStr.Length-1-endIndex), TextColor = Color.Black, FontSize = 20};
            formattedString.Spans.Add(span3);

            label.FormattedText = formattedString;
        }

        else
        {
            label.Text = urlStr;
        }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am using the custom label. So How can I get the hyperlink click event?

Comment: You could use TapGesture .

Comment: Unfortunately the tapgesturerecogniser would only catch a tap on the label as a whole, however in my specific case I need to more specifically catch hypertext links clicks inside the label. For example if a message was received saying "hi, visit www.google.com or www.bing.com" i'd need to be able to click on either, thus my use of the native hyperlink detectors.

Comment: You could use Span . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59711815/creating-xamarin-forms-view-that-shows-paragraph-where-each-sentence-is-clickabl/59712574#59712574 .

Comment: Hi, In my case, the incoming messages may or may not contain URL. So currently the label in incoming message template will show that. So how can I use the span in this case? Currently URL will automatically highlighted and clicked. I just need to navigate to internal browser. Should I do any platform specific implementation?

Comment: Hi bro..This is my exact problem. I just expanded it..I need to navigate to internal browser. thats all.  Should I edit my question?

Comment: You could check if the  string contains like "www" or "http"

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for the suggestion. In https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70903/i-would-like-to-open-hyperlinks-in-app-using-webview-rather-than-an-external-browser  the answer uses a customurl span. But I am confused to how to use it. I think that will solve my problem.. Currently there is no tap for chat list item..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205990/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-androdevil).

Comment: Bro can you check this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59769490/xamarin-forms-open-hyperlink-in-webview

Comment: Hi bro, It always adding an extra letter at the end of url

Comment: `Span span3 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(endIndex+1, urlStr.Length-endIndex-1), TextColor = Color.Black, FontSize = 20};`