# Highlight URL using label span - xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a chat application in xamarin.forms.What I am trying to achieve is whenever user typed message contains a URL, that should be highlighted and provide click to it.For this feature I found Span in Label text.When user click on send button of chat , I will check for URL and make it as another span.I got this idea from *Lucas Zhang - MSFT* form this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745805/xamarin-open-hyperlink-in-native-webview/59746488?noredirect=1#comment105642968_59746488).

The problem is I am trying to do the spanning in view model and the individual chat bubble is in another view cell which will call as ItemTemplate in my chat listview. Anyway the spanning is not working as I intended ie; it doesn't highlight .

**My view Model**.

```
public Queue<Message> DelayedMessages { get; set; } = new Queue<Message>();
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages { get; set; } = new  ObservableCollection<Message>();                                         
public string TextToSend { get; set; }

public ChatPageViewModel()
            {                        
                OnSendCommand = new Command(() =>
                {

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextToSend))
                    {

                        var urlStr = TextToSend;

                        int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;

                        if (urlStr.Contains("www."))
                        {
                            startIndex = urlStr.IndexOf("www.");
                        }

                        if (urlStr.Contains(".com"))
                        {
                            endIndex = urlStr.IndexOf(".com") + 3;
                        }

                        if (startIndex != 0 || endIndex != 0)
                        {
                            var formattedString = new FormattedString();

                            Span span1 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(0, startIndex), TextColor = Color.Black };

                            formattedString.Spans.Add(span1);

                            Span span2 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1), TextColor = Color.LightBlue };
                            span2.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer()
                            {
                                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
                                Command = new Command(() => {


                                })
                            });

                            formattedString.Spans.Add(span2);

                            Span span3 = new Span() { Text = urlStr.Substring(endIndex, urlStr.Length - 1 - endIndex), TextColor = Color.Black };
                            formattedString.Spans.Add(span3);
                            var message = new Message
                            {
                                Text = formattedString.ToString(),
                                IsIncoming = false,
                                MessageDateTime = DateTime.Now
                            };
                            Messages.Add(message);
                            TextToSend = string.Empty;
                        }

                        else
                        {                  
                            var message = new Message
                            {
                                Text = urlStr.ToString(),
                                IsIncoming = false,
                                MessageDateTime = DateTime.Now
                            };
                            Messages.Add(message);
                            TextToSend = string.Empty;
                        }               
                    }                                  
                });        
            }
```

**Single chat Bubble XAML**

```
<Label  x:Name="OutgoingMessage" TextColor="White"  FormattedText="{Binding Text}" HorizontalOptions="End" >              
</Label>
```

**My Chat page XAML**

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" Margin="0,20,0,0"
       ColumnSpacing="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0" 
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MessageTemplateSelector}" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding Messages,Mode=OneWay}" 
             Margin="0"       
             SelectionMode="None"                                  
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft"                               
             HasUnevenRows="True" x:Name="ChatList"
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
             SeparatorColor="Transparent"
             >
     </ListView>
    <BoxView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HeightRequest="1"
             BackgroundColor="#F2F3F5"
             Grid.Row="1"/>
    <partials:ChatInputBarView Grid.Row="2"
                               Margin="0,0,0,0"
                               x:Name="chatInput"/>
</Grid>
```

**ChatPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public partial class ChatPage : ContentPage
    {
        ChatPageViewModel vm;
        public ChatPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = vm= new ChatPageViewModel();                      
        }     
    }
```

**Messages class**

```
 public class Message : ObservableObject
    {
        string text;
        public string Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
        }

        DateTime messageDateTime;

        public DateTime MessageDateTime
        {
            get { return messageDateTime; }
            set { SetProperty(ref messageDateTime, value); }
        }

        public string MessageTimeDisplay => MessageDateTime.Humanize();

        bool isIncoming;

        public bool IsIncoming
        {
            get { return isIncoming; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isIncoming, value); }
        }

    }
```

Any Help is appreciated.

**EDIT**:
This question was actually continuation of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745805/xamarin-open-hyperlink-in-native-webview/59746488?noredirect=1#comment105642968_59746488). Previously I used AwesomeHyperLinkLabel  from[link](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2016/03/10/so-i-created-this-awesomehyperlinklabel-custom-renderer-control-one-day-for-xamarin-forms/). The problem was I cant manage the click event of that label.Thats why I moved with label span.Thanks to **Leo Zhu - MSFT** For the render changes.

Comment: Doing the spanning in ViewModel would break the MVVM pattern don't you think, Why do you need it there anyway?

Comment: That is where I assigning the messages to chat bubble.

Comment: You must be adding it onto a List or something right?

Comment: @FreakyAli yes bro.. The chat bubble xaml is actually a Viewcell which will be assigned to listview by a MessageTemplateSelector

Comment: i saw your last question in your link,actually you just want to use HyperLink Label,it would highlight the url automatically. you just need make a few minor changes like that solution you point out,handle the click event and tell your page to use webview open the url

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT The problem with hyperlink label was, I couldn't get the click event. because it manages in natively I think.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT . If I able manage the click event in hyperlink label, then there is no need of span

Comment: @AndroDevil you could handle the click event in your renderer

Comment: @AndroDevil i would give an example below,you could check it.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT That exactly what I want.

Comment: @AndroDevil but it was for Android,I don't know much about ios, but I think it has a similar way of listening to click events

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Can you help me to get for ios too? Then It will be great help.Please  share the click event manage in android

Comment: @AndroDevil  you could check it,let me know if it works

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Ok bro....let me check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was with my model.Changed string to FormattedString and also changed in the viewmodel

```
 public class Message : ObservableObject
    {
        FormattedString text;
        public FormattedString Text
        {
            get { return text; }
            set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
        }

        DateTime messageDateTime;

        public DateTime MessageDateTime
        {
            get { return messageDateTime; }
            set { SetProperty(ref messageDateTime, value); }
        }

        public string MessageTimeDisplay => MessageDateTime.Humanize();

        bool isIncoming;

        public bool IsIncoming
        {
            get { return isIncoming; }
            set { SetProperty(ref isIncoming, value); }
        }

    }
```

Comment: you could mark yourself as the solution,it will help others with similar issue

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Ok bro.. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**For Android:**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabel), typeof(AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
public class AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{

    public AwesomeHyperLinkLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (AwesomeHyperLinkLabel)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            TextView textView = new TextView(Forms.Context);
            textView.LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            textView.SetTextColor(view.TextColor.ToAndroid());

            // Setting the auto link mask to capture all types of link-able data
            textView.AutoLinkMask = MatchOptions.All;
            // Make sure to set text after setting the mask
            textView.Text = view.Text;
            AddHyperlinksManually(textView);
            //textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, (float)view.FontSize);
            // overriding Xamarin Forms Label and replace with our native control
            SetNativeControl(textView);
        }
    public static void AddHyperlinksManually(TextView _tv)
    {
        SpannableStringBuilder currentSpan = new SpannableStringBuilder(_tv.Text);
        Linkify.AddLinks(currentSpan, MatchOptions.WebUrls);

        var objects = currentSpan.GetSpans(0, currentSpan.Length(), Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(URLSpan)));
        var urlSpans = new URLSpan[objects.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < urlSpans.Length; i++)
        {
            urlSpans[i] = objects[i] as URLSpan;
        }

        foreach (URLSpan _url in urlSpans)
        {
            int iStart = currentSpan.GetSpanStart(_url);
            int iEnd = currentSpan.GetSpanEnd(_url);

            currentSpan.RemoveSpan(_url);
            currentSpan.SetSpan(new CustomURLSpan(_url.URL), iStart, iEnd, SpanTypes.InclusiveInclusive);
            _tv.SetText(currentSpan, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

            _tv.MovementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.Instance;
        }
    }
    public class CustomURLSpan : ClickableSpan
    {
        string mTargetURL;

        public CustomURLSpan(string _url) {
            mTargetURL =_url;
    }

        public override void OnClick(Android.Views.View widget)
        {
            //here you could handle the click event,and you could use MessagingCenter to send mTargetURL to your Page.
            Console.WriteLine("Click");
        }
    }
}
```